# JavaScript false Boolean evaluates as true after assign as false

Tags: node.js, typescript

My variable keeps evaluating as true and goes inside the IF block. How is this possible? Even after I assign it as false.

```
this.model.hasQ1 = false
console.log('type ', typeof this.model.hasQ1) //don't know why typeof is a string
//const test = this.model.hasQ1 === 'true' //this will error out, but shouldn't if the top is typeof is a string
if(this.model.hasQ1){ //this should be false
    console.log('hasQ1 ', this.model.hasQ1) //this gets printed anyways
}
//output: hasQ1  false
```

Comment: How is hasQ1 defined? It could for example be a setter that transforms the boolean to a string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so did the toString() trick and it evaluates as expected. Can someone explain why? FYI, this is from a Typescript class, but I usually don't have to do this.

```
//model was assign this way, yet appears as a string (see next line)
this.model.hasQ1 = false;

//console log of this model appears like this
....,
hasQ1: 'false' }

//This fixes the issue
if(this.model.hasQ1.toString() === 'true'){
    console.log('I should not see this')
}
```

Comment: What does the class look like?

Comment: And please do not post another question as an answer.

Comment: Maybe the class has a set method that make a .toString()

Answer (score 0):

you can force to compare the variable as string to make sure it works:

```
if(this.model.hasQ1.toString() == "true"){ //this should be false
    console.log('hasQ1 ', this.model.hasQ1) //this gets printed anyways
}
```

Comment: But why man? Answer needs some explanation.

Comment: @AlexHopeO'Connor  I don't know what 'model' object is, but probably its property hasQ1 is defined somewhere as 'string', and probably is the reason why the false value is transform into a string. That's what I assume seeing that the typeof is returning 'string'

Answer (score -1):

```
var model = { hasQ1: null };

model.hasQ1 = false;
console.log('type ', typeof model.hasQ1) //typeof is boolean

if (model.hasQ1) { //this is false
  console.log('hasQ1 ', model.hasQ1) //this is not printed
}
//output: hasQ1  false
```

You have to provide the class in order to figure out what's wrong with your code.